# Interfacing Aurduino with PI screen?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, arduino

Is there a way to take the output from an arduino that normally displays on a small LCD screen and display it instead on a rasperry pi with a 7 inch screen?

Comment: Please read the FAQ on how to ask questions! This q will fall into the category "To broad" and risk to be closed.as there is no signs on investigation, no research, no specifics!

Comment: yes there is ... send the data to the RPi and run code on the RPi to display the data in any format that you choose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already suggested by jsotola, don't take the arduinos output to the LCD and instead establish a common data connection between arduino and pi - like uart - to send the raw data the arduino is capturing.

The pi is then able to render by itself to any attached screen.

Take a look at [these](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=39839) for some guidance in hooking up your devices.

Note that this approach will require additional software on the pi to actually display the data after receiving it. There are, however, endless possibilities to achieve this.

To name a few:

- [GUI application](https://www.baldengineer.com/raspberry-pi-gui-tutorial.html) (which could directly embed the acquisition/communication) process
- [Webserver/Website](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/web-server/apache.md)
- Simple terminal output

Just choose whatever suits your application.